# How can I duplicate an event in the Microsoft Outlook Android application?

Tags: outlook

How can I duplicate an event in the Microsoft Outlook Android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To duplicate a calendar event in Outlook is not straight forward. There is no copy or long-press to copy an event. You have to copy the description on the existing event, create a new event, paste the description, select the attendees and time, etc.

The feature has been requested in [Uservoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/suggestions/13878825-copy-calendar-event) since at least 2016. However, Microsoft has not implemented it yet.

Comment: Now that the UserVoice forums have been retired, I've put a related suggestion in the feedback forum: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/2bc069a1-511f-ee11-a81c-000d3a7a48db